# Is there any medium to easily backup my files in Ubuntu?

Tags: files, backup

I would like to know about how to easily backup my files.

Comment: There are plenty: Deja-Dup comes preinstalled. Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/2598/158442

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Deja Dup** is a simple backup tool and it is installed by default on Ubuntu.

You can find it by searching for **Deja Dup** in the dash.